# Using animations on items

Tags: java, android

I have two problems with the following code. This code is supposed to provide an overflow menu with three options, left, right and down. They must move the button accordingly with default animations. The first problem is that the TransitionManager doesn't work at all. The button moves with no animation whatsoever. And the second problem is, when the button moves to left and right, it gets lost behind action bar, what can I do about it?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    RelativeLayout main_view = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_view);

    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.right:
            if(item.isChecked()){
                item.setChecked(false);
            }
            else
                item.setChecked(true);
            TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(main_view);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams positionRulesRight = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            positionRulesRight.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
            positionRulesRight.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
            button.setLayoutParams(positionRulesRight);
            return true;

        case R.id.left:
            if(item.isChecked()){
                item.setChecked(false);
            }
            else
                item.setChecked(true);
            TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(main_view);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams positionRulesLeft = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            positionRulesLeft.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
            positionRulesLeft.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
            button.setWidth(250);
            button.setHeight(250);
            button.setLayoutParams(positionRulesLeft);
            return true;

        case R.id.down:
            if(item.isChecked()){
                item.setChecked(false);
            }
            else
                item.setChecked(true);
            TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(main_view);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams positionRulesDown = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            positionRulesDown.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
            positionRulesDown.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
            button.setLayoutParams(positionRulesDown);
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }


}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.revolise.animations.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main"
        android:id="@+id/include" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:text="@string/button_text"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```